# I want to make the text overlay in an image which also supports responsive sites

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

The below is HTML code. I am using bootstrap 3 for the design. I placed the text over an image, but the issue occurs as it does not stays in correct position. On resizing the browser the position of the text with background gets misplaced. So please help me how to resolve this issue.

```
<div class = "col-xs-12">
<h3 class="cen-align">STORIES OF CHANGE</h3>
<img src="img/rig_img1.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive image-wrapper" />
<p class="img-ps">Advocating Land Rights for BPL Dalit communities in Alampur village...</p>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.img-ps{
font-size:13px;
text-align:center;
position: absolute; 
left:66px; 
top:143px; 
padding: 10px; 
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
width: 248px; 
color: #FFF; 
margin: 0px;
}
.image-wrapper{
position: relative; 
width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Can you pls add a running fiddle? Your Q's is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you need but does this works for you?

HTML:

```
 <div class = "col-xs-12">
    <h3 class="cen-align">STORIES OF CHANGE</h3>
    <img src="img/rig_img1.jpg" class="image">
    <p>Advocating Land Rights for BPL Dalit communities in Alampur village...</p>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .image { 
   position: relative; 

}

p { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%;
   color: white;
}
```